# Where is great in "Great Britain" coming from?

Tags: meaning

Is it just because of the colonial history of Britain?

Comment: I would call this a [History question.](http://history.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: For what it's worth, I always assumed it was the same kind of usage as "Greater New York" or "Greater Boston" -- meaning the city itself plus all the surrounding suburbs which are heavily tied to it by proximity and economics. In that usage, Great(er) Britain would be Britain plus the surrounding countries it had absorbed most directly. But that's probably incorrect.

Comment: What is great in [Greater Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Poland)?

Comment: @keshlam Almost certainly incorrect, indeed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ptolemy referred to the larger island as great Britain (megale Britannia) and to Ireland as little Britain (mikra Brettania) in his work, [Almagest](http://www.wilbourhall.org/pdfs/HeibergAlmagestComplete.pdf) (147–148 AD).

Later on it was called Brittanie Majore to distinguish it from Brittany in France, which was also mostly inhabited by Celts.

Comment: It's worth noting that in Irish we refer to Wales as "Little Britain" (An Bhreatain Bheag).

Comment: @SeanD and in Wales we refer to Ireland as Iwerddon, which is awfully similar to Ywerddon, which means fairy land.

Comment: The year `147`...damn Britain is *ancient*...

Answer (score 16):

[Great Britain](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Greate%20Britain&searchmode=none)

> c.1400, Grete Britaigne. As opposed to Brittany.

[Brittany](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Greate%20Britain&searchmode=none)

> French Bretagne, named for 5c. Romano-Celtic refugees from the Anglo-Saxon invasion of Britain who crossed the channel and settled there (see Britain). The Little Britain or Less Britain (lasse brutaine, c.1300) of old, contrasted with the Great Britain.

Comment: So what you're saying is that "Great" means "Large". Always best to be explicit! (Although I had thought that it was "Great" after the Union with Scotland, rather than compared to Brittany; I didn't realise it was three hundred years older.)

Comment: "Great Britain" is the island comprising England, Scotland, and Wales. Comes from the Romans I believe, in contrast to "Little Britain" which was Ireland.

Comment: I think some people think of "Great Britain" as if it referred to a country (the UK). It doesn't, except when using some specialised senses of "country". In some sporting contexts, for example, the national boundaries of the "countries" used do indeed fall between the islands instead of between the nations. It's confusing, especially since the adjective "British" is often used to mean "of the UK".

Comment: And then there's another meaning of "Great Britain". In "The United  Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", it refers to the union of England, Scotland, and Wales (the *nations*, in other words including the islands that belonged to them).

Comment: @Rupe: If that were "island" I would agree with you (but of course that's not really *another* meaning).

Comment: @TimLymington Sorry, I'm not following you.

Comment: @Rupe: England, Scotland and Wales share an island, which is called Great Britain.

Comment: @Rupe in other words, the singular "island" is correct, as all three (England, Scotland, and Wales) are on the same island.  You used the plural "islands".

Comment: @Doc But I meant the plural. The nations including the islands that belong to them (The Isle of Wight, Anglesey, loads of Scottish islands). In that context "Great Britain", described geographically, comprises more than one island.

Comment: @Rupe Oh, I agree, I was just trying to explain what I believed TimLymington was getting at.

Comment: I recently saw this great [Venn Diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjrr7.gif) explaining the various terms used in conjunction with Britain.

Comment: Of course, this diagram is good but doesn't encompass the UK's oversea territories which are Anguilla, Bermuda, the British Antarctic Territory, the British Indian Ocean Territory, the British Virgin Islands, the Cayman Islands, the Falkland Islands, Gibraltar, Montserrat, Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha, the Turks and Caicos Islands, the Pitcairn Islands, South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands.

Comment: If someone came here trying to research a Geography paper or something the above diagram could cause confusion, all I'm saying

Comment: It will be fun reconstructing the diagram (like one I've used with my staff) if/when Scotland goes its own way.

Comment: In terms of political geography, the Isle of Wight, etc., are part of the United Kingdom. In terms of toponymy, Great Britain is the big island, not including the wee bits off its shores. Similarly, on this side of the Atlantic, Long Island refers to one island, not also the wee bits such as Fire Island that lie just off its shores.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Now "large", but "old". Some countries use "lower" instead of "little".